# how to resolve system security exception by using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filesystemobject

in one of the case i have got the 
 `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)` when am trying to create a file and writing data using file system object in vb.net

```
DIM fso,file
const ForWriting = 2
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
file= fso.opentextfile("C:\test\log.csv",ForWriting,True)
file.write("This,is,a,sampledata")
file.close()
```

How can i sort out this issue, kindly advice.

Comment: If this is VB.Net, use the System.IO namespace instead of the old FileSystemObject. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell i have declared the namespace already,this is first it was came suddenly,again after even with out changing any thing i can able create file also, in which scenarios it throw error, how can i resolve it ?

Comment: @jordell can this help me sort out :   http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/setting-permissions-to-access-database-step-by-step-guide-96087.html

Comment: There error is being thrown because either, you don't have permission to edit the `"C:\test\log.csv"` file or because the file is in use by another. You need to know what user you code is running as and make sure that have permissions to this file and ensure that the files is not in use by another process or user. All that aside, using the legact FileSystemObject is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using the legacy COM `FileSystemObject`, unless it is absolutely necessary, is a bad idea.  Using managed libraries from the .NET framework will provide you with better error information.  For instance, you could accomplish the exact same thing simply by doing:

```
Try
    File.WriteAllText("C:\test\log.csv", "C:\test\log.csv")
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Handle the exception.  See ex.ToString() for full info.
End Try
```

Comment: but one thing i would like to understand, why permission denied it was saying,what kind off permissionwe need to set?what advantage will get by using the your snippet, will it resolve the issue? please help me out on this

Comment: First, it's using managed assemblies instead of COM.  That means it will throw standard .NET exceptions rather than a COM error.  The .NET exceptions have much more info including a stack trace.  This could help you determine why exactly it's failing.  Avoiding COM also means you can compile to any CPU, your distribution is simplified, your code is easier to read and maintain, etc., etc.  Try this and post the exception that you get so we can help you from there.  Usually it's because the file is in use by another application (or even your own), or it's read only.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with JScript, but only if i create the file before.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fso.CreateTextFile(filename);
```

If the file exsists already i can read or write to the file.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

// Create the file, and obtain a file object for the file.
var filename = "testfile.txt";

//here no create! --> fso.CreateTextFile(filename);
var fileObj = fso.GetFile(filename);

// Open a text stream for output.
var ts = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault);

// Write to the text stream.
ts.WriteLine("Hello World!");
ts.WriteLine("The quick brown fox");
ts.Close();
```

It works but it is a workaround if you know the files you need.
Otherwise you will get System.Security.SecurityException: HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED).

**EDIT::** MSDN says:
In the code shown above, the CreateObject function returns the FileSystemObject (fs). The CreateTextFile method then creates the file as a TextStream object (a), and the WriteLine method writes a line of text to the created text file. The Close method flushes the buffer and closes the file.

So i tried this and it works for me:

```
var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
var TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0;

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

// Create the file, and obtain a file object for the file.
var filename = "testfile.txt";
var tss = fso.CreateTextFile(filename);
tss.close();
var fileObj = fso.GetFile(filename);

// Open a text stream for output.
var ts = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault);

// Write to the text stream.
ts.WriteLine("Hello World!");
ts.WriteLine("The quick brown fox");
ts.Close();
```

After create the file you have to close it first, because the createFileMethod create the file as TextStream object. As long it is created as TextStream it is locked on the filesystem.